# Get user's profile picture and other properties using code

Tags: web-part, user-profile

I have a sharepoint group, and I want to list all users in this group in a web part, and show their profile pictures and other properties and display them, I am not sure if I should use code to get info from the managed metadata or this data should be available in the users list in the web I have? What's the way to do it? thanks

Comment: SharePoint 2013?

Comment: Yes, it's 2013 enterprise.

Comment: Did you try to access this list (user information list), there is an example of using code also --> http://zimmergren.net/technical/sharepoints-hidden-user-list-user-information-list

Comment: Hi Nachitek, I could get the user image and user job title from the article you provided, that's been great, but how do I get a link to the user profile as well? I can't see any property represeting url to his profile

Comment: You can't use the user information list. You need to access the UPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [SPWeb.SiteUserInfoList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.siteuserinfolist.aspx) to get the users (`UserInfo`)  of the site collection (`RenderUsers` method) and then render User profile link (`RenderUser` method) as demonstrated below:

```
        private void RenderUsers(SPWeb web, int groupId, HtmlTextWriter output)
        {
            var query = new SPQuery();
            query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"ID\"/><FieldRef Name=\"Title\"/><FieldRef Name=\"SipAddress\"/><FieldRef Name=\"Name\"/><FieldRef Name=\"ContentTypeId\"/>";
            query.Query = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "<Where><And><Membership Type=\"SPGroup\" ID=\"{0}\"><FieldRef Name=\"ID\"/></Membership><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"IsActive\"></FieldRef><Value Type=\"Boolean\">1</Value></Eq></And></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\"Title\"/></OrderBy>", groupId);
            var users = web.SiteUserInfoList.GetItems(query);
            foreach (SPListItem listItem in users)
                RenderUser(web, listItem, output);
        }

        public  void RenderUser(SPWeb web, SPListItem item, HtmlTextWriter output)
        {
            var userId = item.ID;
            var userName = (string)item["Title"];
            output.Write("<a href=\"" + SPHttpUtility.HtmlUrlAttributeEncode(SPHttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(MakeLayoutsServerRelative(web, "userdisp.aspx"), true)) + "?id=" + userId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            output.Write("\">");
            output.Write(SPHttpUtility.HtmlEncode(userName));
            output.Write("</a>");
        }


        private static string MakeLayoutsServerRelative(SPWeb web,string relativePath)
        {
            try
            {
                return SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(web.ServerRelativeUrl+ "/_layouts/", relativePath);
            }
            catch
            {
                return (string)null;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've not given a lot of details, so my example is via REST.

You access properties of a groups using the following REST endpoint:

`_api/web/sitegroups`

For example you might send a REST call to the following URL where the number 15 is the ID of the group you want the members of.

`_api/web/sitegroups(15)?$select=Title,Users&$expand=Users`

This will return a JSON object with an array of Users.

```
{
    "d": {
        "__metadata": {
            "id": "https://sharepoint.domain.com.com/_api/Web/SiteGroups/GetById(15)",
            "uri": "https://sharepoint.domain.com.com/_api/Web/SiteGroups/GetById(15)",
            "type": "SP.Group"
        },
        "Users": {
            "results": [
                {
                    "__metadata": {
                        "id": "https://sharepoint.domain.com.com/_api/Web/GetUserById(19)",
                        "uri": "https://sharepoint.domain.com.com/_api/Web/GetUserById(19)",
                        "type": "SP.User"
                    },
                    "Groups": {
                        "__deferred": {
                            "uri": "https://sharepoint.domain.com.com/_api/Web/GetUserById(19)/Groups"
                        }
                    },
                    "Id": 12,
                    "IsHiddenInUI": false,
                    "LoginName": "dom\\rkaucher",
                    "Title": "Robert Kaucher",
                    "PrincipalType": 1,
                    "Email": "useremail@domain.com",
                    "IsSiteAdmin": false,
                    "UserId": {
                        "__metadata": {
                            "type": "SP.UserIdInfo"
                        },
                        "NameId": "10033fff86ac7f50",
                        "NameIdIssuer": "urn:federation:microsoftonline"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "Title": "portal Members"
    }
}
```

Then, for each user in the array you will need to get the profile picture's URL via:

`"_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='PictureURL')?@v='" + LoginName + "'";`

Comment: I am not giving a lot of details because I don't know how to do it, I don't know anyway to do it, so I am asking for guidance here. I have already replied to your question if it's SP 2013 or 2010. Thanks

Comment: OK, but would you use JavaScript? jQuery? Some other framework? Or would you be writing a Visual Web Part using C#? I understand not knowing how to do something but in order to provide a decent answer we need to know at least which methods you would choose to approach the problem.

Comment: Thanks Robert, 

I am trying to create a visual web part in C#, to list all users from a specific group into the page, I could do so with the method in the blog post mentioned above, but I stopped at the url to the user profile itself. I don't want data about specific user, I want to roll the data about multiple users and get link to their profiles, using c#.

Comment: @Robert, can you share references which contains full code? I'm trying to reproduce the code that you provided and using this [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432.aspx#bk_Group) I can't get call works.